# How to use/implement SoftAssert feature in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I have used TestNG SoftAssert feature in Java where we do multiple verifications and store result of each verification in SoftAssert and at the end of test case assert test case with all verification results.

I could not found a similar feature in Robot Framework. Does anyone know how to implement this feature or use it if exists in RobotFramework?

Comment: show your code trials

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Dev .. I was exploring suitable keyword in RF. Bryan has provided a solution to my query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Run keyword and continue on failure](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Continue%20On%20Failure). If the keyword you run fails, the test will continue to run and report the failure at the end.

Example:

Here is a test that uses this keyword:

```
*** Test cases ***
Example
    run keyword and continue on failure  log   this passes
    run keyword and continue on failure  fail  this is a failure
    run keyword and continue on failure  log   this also passes
    run keyword and continue on failure  fail  this is also a failure
```

When run, you will see this on the console:

```
==============================================================================
Example                                                                          
==============================================================================
Example                                                               | FAIL |
Several failures occurred:

1) this is a failure

2) this is also a failure
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Junk                                                                  | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
```

You could also use that keyword as the value for a test template, though I don't think I would recommend it as a standard practice:

```
*** Test cases ***
Example
    [template]  run keyword and continue on failure
    log   this passes
    fail  this is a failure
    log   this also passes
    fail  this is also a failure
```

Comment: Perfect! This is what I was looking for! Thanks @Bryan